# How to destroy local variables if exceptions thrown by a function may be uncaught?

Tags: c++, exception, uncaught-exception

When a function throws while the exception is uncaught, stack unwinding is unlikely to trigger, so destructors of local variables won't be called. For example, the following code outputs only "created" (and the error messages) under g++ 7.1.0:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    A() { cerr << "created\n"; }
    ~A() { cerr << "destroyed\n"; }
};

void f() {
    A a;
    throw 0;
}

int main() {
    f();
}
```

This may lead to memory leaks upon crashing if `A` allocates memory, and whether the memory will be freed depends on the OS.

A possible solution I find is wrap `f()` in a function try-catch block:

```
void f() try {
    A a;
    throw 0;
} catch (...) {
    throw;
}
```

In this way destructor of `a` is always called. However, I don't find it satisfying because an empty catch clause has to be written, and it's not straightforward.

So which of the following should be considered correct, or if there's better practice (especially when implementing a function in a library) ?

1. Wrap every potentially-throwing function with try-catch block mentioned above;
2. Pretend the callers to this function always catches the exception;
3. Because uncaught exception causes crashing, I don't have to destruct local variables.

Comment: You don't need to _destroy_ anything explicitely. The local variables will be gone as if the scope was left. 3. is correct.

Comment: Was this an exam question?

Comment: Reopening. The linked question is about the case where unwinding happens, this is about where unwinding doesn't happen because the exception is uncaught.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Hmm. The answer from the dupe had a standard  cite that also covered that. What a waste.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well I find local variables only destroyed if the exception is caught somewhere. At least the example I gave says so.

Comment: @TRCYX As mentioned 3. is correct. What are you actually worrying about?

Comment: In large systems, a single application program is usually part of a bigger solution with many processes interacting with each other and the OS (itself possibly running on a VM) orchestrating and scheduling things, not to mention distributed systems with load balancers and other sophisticated stuff. What should happen when a single application process crashes and if/how it is restarted, how resources are reclaimed etc. is then not the application's own concern, but that of the upper layer which started the application in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Put a top-level try-catch(...) in your `main` function that outputs an error message and exits. This will ensure that unwinding always happens.

Though the question is why you would want that. If you're in any real-world non-embedded environment, the OS *will* clean up all resources of your process. There's no maybe about it. And since there are other ways for a process to crash which don't involve exceptions, you can't rely on destructors for cleanup in such a case anyway.

If you're in an embedded environment, the situation is similar. You don't have an OS to clean up, maybe, but crashes usually lead to a device reset, which has the same effect. And again, you can't rely on destructors because there are other ways to crash.

Comment: Well in an embedded system, some peripheral HW could be left in a bad state and a complete power on reset might be necessary.

Comment: Possibly. But as I said, you can't rely on destructors for that.

Comment: Well, that's a nice idea to convince me stop overthinking about this. :-D

Comment: Even in non-embedded there might be specific cases where this might be significant ... for example, when the constructor locks a semaphore in a shared memory and the destructor unlocks it. If the destructor is not called, the lock will remain locked forever (until the machine is rebooted or the shared memory explicitly cleaned).

Comment: @axalis True, but that's another instance of the "yeah, but what if you segfault?" problem. You have to come up with a solution for abandoned semaphores anyway.

Comment: IINM, you should add it not only in `main`, but in any thread function as well (of which `main` is just a private case). Asides from this nitpicking comment, this answer seems the way to go, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, that is specifically a bug which I have found recently (and was pretty difficult to debug). There were instances, where a shared memory lock of a service was "hold" somehow, although there was no active client which could hold the lock. At the end I figured out, that if the client was terminated by Ctrl+C at a wrong timepoint, the lock remained locked (not solved yet, catching exceptions does not help in this case, will require a signal handler to be implemented or something alike).